# Screen video capture application

Tags: macos, video, screen-capture

I am Looking for a program that let's me capture screen videos on Mac OS X.

I am requesting it for these two use cases:

1. Capture of a webcam. It should allow capturing only the webcam App window.
2. Creation of program tutorials. Ideally, it should allow mouse cursor magnification and visual click representation (like, making some visual effect when you click on anything).

A different program for each case use is fine if there is not a program that can do both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research I've learnt that for the second use case you can use a separate program that does mouse magnification and keystroke detection in conjunction with a regular screen recording program like Quicktime Player (included on Mac OS X). [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) seems the most recommended one.

As for a standalone screen capture program that has more features than Quicktime Player, I've found four that are maybe the most widely used ones:

- [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm)
- [Camtasia for Mac](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/)
- [iShowU](http://store.shinywhitebox.com/ishowuhd/main.html)
- [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/)

ScreenFlow offers mouse cursor customization, and iShowU offers keystroke and mouse action recording, for showing in the video. ScreenFlow, iShowYou and Camtasia are looking great. Snapz Pro X seems more focused to regular screenshot capturing, but does video as well.

Comment: would you please provide link for software recommended.

Comment: Links provided and self-answer greatly improved, props to Martín Marconcini for providing useful info on this other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/how-to-record-the-screen-of-an-opengl-application-without-stuttering

Answer (score 8):

I've found that "New Screen Recording" functionality in QuickTime Player combined with iMovie editing capabilities is enough for my needs. Maybe you can give it a try? Best of all, it's already installed on your Mac. Unfortunately, I can't compare it with Camtasia, as I haven't used it.

Answer (score 6):

There's [a question about recording the screen of an OpenGL application without stuttering](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/how-to-record-the-screen-of-an-opengl-application-without-stuttering/2762#2762) here at StackExchange.

Answer (score 5):

My firsthand experience with [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) has been great for creating tutorials. It includes cursor magnification, cursor and window highlighting, etc., and a decent editor.

I agree that Camtasia looks great, too, but I've not tried it.

Comment: ScreenFlow looks very promising indeed, specially with all the speed and performance optimizations that are advertised on their website. Does it allow to capture just a part of the screen (or crop it after capturing on the included editor)?

Answer (score 4):

If it comes down to choosing between Camstasia for Mac and Screenflow, here's a side by side comparison: http://www.skillcasting.com/comparison-camtasia-mac-vs-screenflow/

Answer (score 3):

Try [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/). Free version have no cam support, but if you really need it there's a pro version for $14.90 / year. Great app, mac style.

Answer (score 2):

## In 2018, Mojave introduced a new shortcut to do screen recordings.

**cmd + shift + 5**

In the options you can choose to show mouse clicks (or not).

And you can select a portion of the screen to record if you don't want it all.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you undoubtedly that there is one piece of software that is the cream of the crop when it comes to video recording on Mac. And it's FREE!

**OBS Studio** - https://obsproject.com/

I've tried many screen recorders, most of them have limited trials unless you buy the full version of the software.
And many of them (including QuickTime) save in .mov format with bad transcoding resulting in huge file sizes. OBS videos are tiny even in crisp HD.

What also makes OBS really great is that you can add different scenes with different video and audio sources and seamlessly swap between your monitor recording built-in auto and swap to your webcam using external microphone audio.

You can also live stream directly from OBS.

Did I mention it's FREE!