# Screen video capture application OS 10.5.8 (Leopard)

Tags: macos, video, leopard, screen-capture

Are there any freeware/shareware application to make a screen videocapture compatible with OSX 10.5.8?

Comment: Is the screen [videocapture](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/7663/10733) feature of Quicktime not available in 10.5.8. Can you update QuickTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenium app supports 10.5 and higher 
http://www.syniumsoftware.com/screenium/

Old versions of ScreenFlow supports 10.5
https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26915/screenflow

Answer (score 1):

If you can update [QuickTime](https://www.apple.com/quicktime/) you can perform a video capture very easily with a native application.

Are you looking for something specifically that is freeware? Here are some suggestions from [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4495/10733).